# httpd not listed in process list although its running without any issue

Tags: linux

How to check the process status if process is running and not listed in ps or top command output.

I have started httpd(Apache) service and its working perfectly, i am able to see the webpage. But top or ps command doesn't display the httpd process.

What is the issue? I am logged in as root user.
Can we check the process status by any command if process id is not listed?

```
[root@ip-xx-xxx-xx-xxx /]# service httpd restart
Stopping httpd:                                            [  OK  ]
Starting httpd:                                            [  OK  ]
```

```
top - 19:54:08 up 10 days,  5:04,  1 user,  load average: 0.00, 0.01, 0.05
Tasks:  70 total,   1 running,  69 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
Cpu(s):  0.0%us,  0.0%sy,  0.0%ni,100.0%id,  0.0%wa,  0.0%hi,  0.0%si,  0.0%st
Mem:    617044k total,   307312k used,   309732k free,    30660k buffers
Swap:        0k total,        0k used,        0k free,   218968k cached

  PID USER      PR  NI  VIRT  RES  SHR S %CPU %MEM    TIME+  COMMAND
    1 root      20   0  2892 1360 1164 S  0.0  0.2   0:00.34 init
    2 root      20   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.01 kthreadd
    3 root      20   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:01.82 ksoftirqd/0
    4 root      RT   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 migration/0
    5 root      RT   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 watchdog/0
    6 root      20   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:26.84 events/0
    7 root      20   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 cpuset
    8 root      20   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 khelper
   11 root      20   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 netns
   12 root      20   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 async/mgr
   17 root      20   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 xenwatch
   18 root      20   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 xenbus
   64 root      20   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:02.37 sync_supers
   66 root      20   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:02.58 bdi-default
   67 root      20   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 kintegrityd/0
   69 root      20   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.03 kblockd/0
   76 root      20   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 kseriod
  184 root      20   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.16 khungtaskd
  185 root      20   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 kswapd0
  186 root      25   5     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 ksmd
  238 root      20   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 aio/0
  241 root      20   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 crypto/0
  252 root      20   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 khvcd
  332 root      20   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 kstriped
  519 root      20   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.37 jbd2/xvda1-8
  520 root      20   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 ext4-dio-unwrit
  548 root      20   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 khubd
  599 root      16  -4  2504  644  352 S  0.0  0.1   0:00.02 udevd
  824 root      20   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.09 kauditd
  858 root      18  -2  2500  640  352 S  0.0  0.1   0:00.00 udevd
  859 root      18  -2  2500  636  348 S  0.0  0.1   0:00.00 udevd
  983 root      20   0  2840  760  488 S  0.0  0.1   0:00.01 dhclient
 1020 root      16  -4 10896  580  428 S  0.0  0.1   0:00.85 auditd
 1035 root      20   0 29628 1436  964 S  0.0  0.2   0:01.37 rsyslogd
 1056 dbus      20   0  2980  884  700 S  0.0  0.1   0:00.58 dbus-daemon
 1151 root      20   0  8192  888  468 S  0.0  0.1   0:00.43 sshd
 1171 ntp       20   0  5072 1368 1036 S  0.0  0.2   0:01.34 ntpd
```

Comment: or `ps -ef | grep http`?

Comment: yes working but why top or ps without any parameter is not listing that process.

Comment: i got it, top -u apache lists httpd service. UID is basically apache instead of root.31532 apache    20   0 29488 3852  420 S  0.0  0.6   0:00.00 httpd

Comment: @Praveen - `ps` alone only lists the processes of the current user. The `a` and `x` options are needed since `a` will list processes from all users, and `x` will display processes that are run as daemons (like `httpd` is normally).

Comment: thanks, i was not aware the apache named some user exists. i thought root owns httpd service.

Answer (score 1):

I prefer to use:

```
pgrep -l httpd
```

Example:

```
[root@mywebserver ~]$ pgrep -l httpd
3661 httpd
3665 httpd
3673 httpd
3678 httpd
3683 httpd
3688 httpd
3694 httpd
3701 httpd
: .. more....
```

Counting those lines also helps me to see if the server is getting overloaded.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ ps -efw |grep -i httpd
```

also

```
$ top
```

press: u == display user

```
'u'
```

followed by the username, in this case 'apache' enter:

```
apache
```